# Configuring Virtual Machine Acceleration for Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to set up an emulator for VM acceleration using the instructions here: [Using the Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm).

The setup says:

> You must use an AVD that is uses an x86 system image target. AVDs that
> use ARM-based system images cannot be accelerated using the emulator
> configurations described here.

Then it says:

> To use virtual machine acceleration with the emulator, you need the
> following version of Android development tools. Use the Android SDK
> Manager to install these components:
>
> Android SDK Tools, Revision 17 or higher
>
> Android x86-based system
> image

I have the latest Android SDK Tools.  However in my SDK Manager, I do not have any "Android x86-based system" available to install.  I also don't have any x86 system image option to install for any specific API version.

For those that set this up successfully, how did you use the Android SDK Manager to install the "Android x86-based system image"?

I believe I have done all of the other setup needed, including running IntelHAXM.exe and confirming that the virtualization driver is operating correctly.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the instructions are slightly misleading, you need to use the Android Virtual Device Manager to create an x86 type AVD. If you start the AVD manager and press 'New' to create one, then under the targets at the API level 10, you should see an '**Intel Atom x86 image**'. That's the one you want. There are no other API levels available at the moment, though I think more are planned fro later.

Comment: This helps, thanks a lot!  'Intel Atom x86 image' was not available in the AVD manager for API 10 until I installed it for API 10 from the SDK Manager.  Once I did that the AVD manager had that option.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Read and follow the instruction [Emulators in Android](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm)